# linked list not Displaying due to segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

The control flow of program is not going into the create List function and I am unable understand. why it is so.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}*head=NULL;

struct Node * createList( int arr[], int n){
       head->data = arr[0];
       head->next = NULL;
       struct Node * last;
       
       last = head;
       for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
                 struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                 newNode->data = arr[i];
                 newNode->next = NULL;
                 last->next  =  newNode;
                 last = newNode;
                 printf("executed ");
       }
       return head;
}
void Display(struct Node * head){
    struct Node * p = head;
   
    while(p!=NULL){
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[]={2,55,2,6,66};

struct Node * result = createList(arr, 5);
Display(result);
return 0;
}
```

I have declared a cout in the the for loop of createList function but it's not printing in terminal hence control is not entering in the function and I have tried several things but still unable to figure out it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to dereference a NULL pointer at the very first statement in `createList`:

```
head->data = arr[0];
```

At this moment `head` is `NULL`, so there is no sense in `head->data`.

You should *first* create (allocate) a node, and only then assign to its `data` member.

Also, you should not define `head` as a global variable. This should be a variable that is local to `createList`, since the caller is anyhow using the returned pointer, not `head`. I would also move the node-creation code in a separate function -- this makes the code more readable.

Finally, to populate a list it will be handy to use a pointer-pointer, so that you can use the same code to set `head` and to set a `next` member:

```c
struct Node * createNode(int data) { // Separate function
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct Node * createList( int arr[], int n){
    struct Node *head = NULL; // Don't use a global variable for this
    struct Node **ref = &head; // Address of the pointer that needs to be updated
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // First iteration will set `head`
         *ref = createNode(arr[i]);
         ref = &(*ref)->next; // The address of the tail node's `next` member
    }
    return head;
}
```